# Compatibilidad de api 22 con api 19

Tags: android, android-studio

He generado un aplicativo el cual corre muy bien sobre sistemas con api de niveles mayores al 20, quise probar con un android s4 mini el cual tiene una api nivel 19(Kit-Kat) alguien me puede ayudar a dar compatibilidad con este sistema.

He revisado algunos tutoriales los cuales me llevaron a modificar el project structure y modificar el compilesdk a versión 19. pero tengo un problema con estas dos lineas de codigo del gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Probe cambiando la primera dependencia a su verion 19.4.0 es decir:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.4.0'
```

y no tengo problemas pero no puedo hacer lo mismo con la segunda dependecia.
Alguien puede ayudarme.
El aplicativo trabaja con el componente navigation drawer

Este es mi archivo gradle completo

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kevtho.aplicacion"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile files('libs/btsdk.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
//compile files('libs/android-support-4.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: porque pones el compile-version a 19? si estableces eso limitas a tu app que la mayor parte de apis solo son las de 19. Normal que no te deje con design: ya que salio en Lollipop para dar compatibilidad a las versiones inferiores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar el problema, resulta que el problema de compatibilidad se daba por que en mi proyecto uso multidex, la solución fue añadir dependencias de esta clase al grade del proyecto. Aquí comparto la información detallada.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas cambiar las dependencias:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

si deseas que tu aplicación sea soportada para dispositivos con Android API 19 simplemente define :

```
 minSdkVersion 19
```

y no cambies `compileSdkVersion` y `buildToolsVersion` puedes usar una versión de acuerdo a las dependencias que has definido

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

lo mismo para `targetSdkVersion` :

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Buenas @Elenasys, recientemente he subido a 25 y se han solventado todos los bugs conocidos de las otras versiones

Comment: Que bien, me parece que el problema es no definir versiones similares,  por ejemplo tienes 23.4.0 pero buildTools es 23.0.3, como quedo esto ahora con versión 25?

Comment: A mi el máximo buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" aun no me notifica que haya nueva versión.

Answer (score 0):

Si no voy mal ecaminado, lo que limita que se pueda ejecutar la app es el `minSdkVersion=19` el `compileSdkVersion` le indicas con que SDK quieres compilar el proyecto.

Supongo que la segunda dependencia que te refieres es a la `com.android.support:dessign:23...` es normal que no la puedes poner a 19, ya que no existia entonces, Google la saco para dar compatibilidad a a la API de Lollipop para versiones anteriores.

Comment: Gracias amigo yo tenia la misma lógica  pero entonces no entiendo la razón del porque no se ejecuta en un celular con api 19